# exec ffmpeg not working for nginx-rtmp-module on AWS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, nginx, rtmp

I was trying out the nginx-rtmp module from https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module. While implementing the example for ffmpeg given in the link, my exec ffmpeg is not getting executed. 
My rtmp config inside nginx.conf file:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;
       application myapp {
        live on;
        exec on;
        allow publish all;
        allow play all;
            exec_static ffmpeg -re -i /home/ubuntu/jwplayer/myVideo.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/livestream;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I remove ffmpeg command from nginx.conf and execute it outside nginx config file, I can view the video streaming. I'm not sure why is it not working when I keep it inside the nginx.conf file. I'm streaming the video on `rtmp://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/livestream` using `jwplayer`.

I also tried using full path for `ffmpeg`. Including PATH variable like `env PATH` didn't work either.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on AWS-ec2. nginx version is 1.2.4.